# How do I pick up an Ectoplasmator in Runescape?

Tags: runescape

How do I pick up an Ectoplamsator in Runescape? While attempting to I get the message

"It slips through your fingers".

How do I get it into my inventory?

Comment: Did you try using Telegrab?

Comment: Oh my god no! Your right thats what I needed to do......

Comment: Sometimes something is so obvious that you just can't think of it. Story of my life.

Comment: @RichardA Ya. It hurts me a little.

Comment: @RichardA Sounds like you found the answer. Why not post it as such?

Comment: @Fluttershy Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [Telegrab](https://runescape.wiki/w/Telekinetic_Grab) those things, that will work guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

You've actually stumbled upon a different version of an ectoplasmator. A "ghost ectoplasmator". There's a chance of obtaining it from a ghost monster such as a Banshee or even a revenant, alongside with the normal ectoplasmator.

And yes, telegrabbing it is the only way to retrieve it.